# How to convert a numeric keyboard to a normal/letters keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I have a finished project made by a friend, but in a textfield he put a numeric keyboard, where it should be a normal keyboard. There is a lot of code and i don't know how to change the keyboard type. 
What word or sentence should i find, and which value needs to change?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you just ask your friend to change it?

Answer (score 2):

It the project uses a storyboard, you should look there first. Open up the story board and find the field that is showing the wrong keyboard. On the right side of the screen, select the attributes inspector. One of the options will be "Keyboard". Change that to the desired keyboard type.

If it is not set there, then you will have to look in the code. You can look for where it is set in code by searching for ***UIKeyboardType***. It will be using one of the following options.

```
UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation
UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad
UIKeyboardTypePhonePad
```

Change one of those to UIKeyboardTypeDefault, and run the app again. There probably won't too many places where you see this, so you should get it right within a few tries.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, select your text field and open Attributes inspector. There's 'Keyboard' attribute. Set it to whatever you need.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Im done of silly questions jaja, buy i dont speak english and its a little harder

Answer (score 0):

```
[textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];
```